# Laravel using subElements in with check in a where case laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

the title is a bit hard to word but what i am looking is I am doing a `Tank::with('oil', 'site')` I then need to do a `->where(site.location, 'LIKE', 'mylocation')->get()` but the site.location isn't taking anything from the site imported with the with check. How would I go about doing this.

And if anyone can thing of a better way to word the title please say so if it does get solved other people can find it easier.

Thank you, Jordan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$result = Tank::with(['oil', 'site' => function($q) use($value) {
    $q->where('location', 'LIKE', $value);
}])->get();
```

> Also you may try this (It will fetch records only if the query returns
>   location you want, otherwise none):

```
$result = Tank::with('oil', 'site')->whereHas('site', function($q){
    $q->where('location', 'LIKE', 'mylocation');
})->get();
```

Comment: @JordanEllison Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: sorry was waiting for the time to pass I tried and it was like wait x mins, doing it now